# Authentication through mod_auth_kerb should provide website with no user if no TGT provided

Tags: apache-2.2, kerberos, mod-auth-kerb

Users are authenticated by mod_auth_kerb which works great. Therefore I need to set

> Require valid-user

If there is no valid user Apache fails with an 401 Authorization Required. I would like Apache to deliver the website anyway but without providing a `REMOTE_USER` to the underlying application (python code, or php script).

This is related to [How to tell mod_auth_kerb to do its job despite no "require valid-user"](https://serverfault.com/questions/204826/how-to-tell-mod-auth-kerb-to-do-its-job-despite-no-require-valid-user). But with the important difference that on a whole sub directory on every URL a Kerberos negotiation should be initiated, and if it fails it should deliver the content anyway.

Comment: It seems not to be possible to achieve this with mod_auth_kerb. Does anyone know an alternative? (If possible for Apache ...)

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to configure Apache to only "try" authenticating.

The way I would handle that is for your application to decide when to try to authenticate the client, by using a session cookie for example. If the client's session is expired, have the application redirect the client to a specific page covered by "Require valid-user" and set up an ErrorDocument that redirects back to the application in case of failure.

Comment: This is a good idea in general and I am investigating this! But I would like to have this behavior not only for a login-site but for the whole website where it gets tricky!

Comment: Maybe have the application check REMOTE_USER and the session cookie during the application's bootstraping phase?

Comment: Yes this is how the application works at the moment. But at this time it is already to late to initialize the Kerberos Authentication.